# What does BigUint::from(24u32) do?

Tags: rust, cryptography

```
BigUint::from(24u32)
```

I understand that it is related to a big unsigned integer since it is part of a cryptography module to factor big numbers. I don't understand what the part `from(24u32)` does.
For example, if it is used in this context

```
let b: BigUint = (BigUint::from(24u32) * &n).sqrt() + &one;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversions between types in Rust are defined by the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait which defines a function `from`, so that `Foo::from (bar)` converts the value `bar` to the type `Foo`. In your case, you are therefore converting `24u32` to type `BigUint`, but what's this `24u32`?

Integer literals in Rust can use a suffix to specify their actual type. If you wrote just `24`, it could be for example an `i32`, a `u8` or a `u32`. Most of the time the compiler is able to infer the actual type from the way the value is used, and when it can't it defaults to `i32`. But in your case that won't work: there is no `BigUint::from<i32>` but there are conversion functions for all the regular unsigned types: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64` and `u128`, so the compiler doesn't know which one to use. Adding the `u32` suffix clarifies the type, so `24u32` is the value `24` with the type `u32`, allowing the compiler to understand that you want `BigUint::from<u32> (24)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `BigUint` struct implements the [`From<u32>` trait](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.4.0/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html#impl-From%3Cu32%3E), which means that it will implement a `from(u32)` function.

Implementations of the [`From<_>` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) are used to perform a value conversion that will consume the original input. In your example the `BigUint` struct is constructed from the `24u32` number.